# How do I get @ViewBag.UserName from Controller to _layout page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I use the @ViewBag.UserName I have defined in my controller to display in my _layout page? Here is the code from the controller:

```
                       var username = User.Identity.Name;

                using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.local"))
                {
                    var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, username);
                    DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        ViewBag.UserName = user.Name;
                        ViewBag.EmailAddress = user.EmailAddress;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `ViewBag`'s life only lasts during the **current http request**. `ViewBag` values will be null if redirection occurs.

You should keep your user information in `Session` variable.

```
if (user != null)
{
    Session["UserName"] = user.Name;
    Session["EmailAddress"] = user.EmailAddress;
}
```

in layout.cshtml

```
<p>@Session["UserName"]</p>
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Viewbag data won't display in the _layout page. If its just a view displayed one time, you can use TempData, but with shared views, the Tempdata will be displayed only for the first view.
So, you should use Session varaible to store the user details and display it in the shared view.